# Merge ranges with guava

Tags: java, guava

I need to merge some ranges.

I discovered guava and see that it can handle it in some cases.

```
RangeSet<Integer> rangeSet = TreeRangeSet.create();
rangeSet.add(Range.closed(1, 10)); // {[1, 10]}
rangeSet.add(Range.closed(8, 15)); // {[1, 15]}
```

Now, I need to tell Guava that I need that `[1, 10] + [11, 20] = {[1, 20]}` and not `{[1, 10], [11, 20]}`.

Is there an option somewhere for this?

Comment: Could you provide an example where this matters?

Comment: It matters with dates but I wanted to keep it simple. If you work from the 1st to the 11th of January and from the 12th to the 20th of January, you actually work from the 1st to 20th. I need to keep the information in a single line in my app.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want ranges like this to be merged, you need to canonicalize them first:

```
rangeSet.add(Range.closed(1, 10).canonical(DiscreteDomain.integers()); 
// {[1, 11)}
rangeSet.add(Range.closed(11, 20).canonical(DiscreteDomain.integers());
// {[1, 21)}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ImmutableRangeSet<Integer> rangeSet = ImmutableRangeSet.<Integer>builder()
        .add(Range.closed(1, 10).canonical(DiscreteDomain.integers()))
        .add(Range.closed(11, 15))
        .build()
```

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I'm not familiar with Guava.

The reason that your two ranges above don't combine is that there is a gap between 10 and 11. To get the ranges to combine you need one of two situations:

1. The end of the first range is greater than the beginning of your second range. (This is the case in the example above)
2. If the first and second range are the same value, they must both be considered "open". The [Guava documentation on ranges](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/RangesExplained) explains how to differentiate between open and closed ranges.

Answer (score 0):

I think `TreeRangeSet` implementation is buggy.

[RangeSet Guava javadoc](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/RangeSet.html) defines the following contract:

> Implementations that choose to support the add(Range) operation are required to ignore >empty ranges and coalesce connected ranges. For example:

```
RangeSet<Integer> rangeSet = TreeRangeSet.create();
rangeSet.add(Range.closed(1, 10)); // {[1, 10]}
rangeSet.add(Range.closedOpen(11, 15)); // disconnected range; {[1, 10], [11, 15)}
rangeSet.add(Range.closedOpen(15, 20)); // connected range; {[1, 10], [11, 20)}
rangeSet.add(Range.openClosed(0, 0)); // empty range; {[1, 10], [11, 20)}
rangeSet.remove(Range.open(5, 10)); // splits [1, 10]; {[1, 5], [10, 10], [11, 20)}
```

Actually the implementation of `TreeRangeSet` does the following (note the difference concerning `[11, 20)` / `[11, 15), (15, 20)`:

```
rangeSet.add(Range.closed(1, 10)); // {[1, 10]}
rangeSet.add(Range.closedOpen(11, 15)); // {[1, 10], [11, 15)}
rangeSet.add(Range.open(15, 20)); // disconnected range; {[1, 10], [11, 15), (15, 20)}
rangeSet.add(Range.openClosed(0, 0)); // empty range; {[1, 10], [11, 15), (15, 20)}
rangeSet.remove(Range.open(5, 10)); // splits [1, 10]; {[1, 5], [10, 10], [11, 15), (15, 20)}}
```

There is several cases:

- `[1, 10] + [11, 15)` are not coalesced, yet they are connected...
- `[10, 15) + (15, 20)` are not coalesced, which is OK since they are disconnected. However, commentaries in the javadoc piece of code says it should be coalesced...
- `[10, 10] + [11, 20)` are not coalesced, yet they are connected...

I think the only way you can do this, until it is fixed, is to add "closedOpen" ranges, with the upper bound set to your actual upperbound + 1:

You can do either @LouisWasserman' way, or:

```
rangeSet.add(Range.closedOpen(1, 11)); // {[1, 11)}
rangeSet.add(Range.closedOpen(11, 21)); // {[1, 21)}
```

You can also create a method to "automate" the upperBound trick, for example:

```
public void addRangeToSet(int lowerBound, int upperBound, RangeSet<Integer> set){
    set.add(Range.closedOpen(lowerBound, upperBound + 1));
}

...

addRangeToSet(1, 10, set); // {[1, 11)}
addRangeToSet(11, 20, set); // {[1, 21)}

rangeSet.add(Range.closedOpen(1, 10)); // {[1, 10)}
rangeSet.add(Range.closedOpen(11, 20)); // {[1, 21)}
```

---

**EDIT**

[`isConnected` method JavaDoc](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Range.html#isConnected%28com.google.common.collect.Range%29) states that:

> Note that certain discrete ranges are not considered connected, even though there are no elements "between them." For example, [3, 5] is not considered connected to [6, 10]. In these cases, it may be desirable for both input ranges to be preprocessed with canonical(DiscreteDomain) before testing for connectedness.

So the "best" approach seems to be the @LouisWesserman's one:

```
rangeSet.add(Range.closed(1, 10).canonical(DiscreteDomain.integers());  // {[1, 11)}
rangeSet.add(Range.closed(11, 20).canonical(DiscreteDomain.integers()); // {[1, 21)}
```

Comment: This is working as intended.   `[1, 10]` and `[11, 15)` are _not_ considered connected by the [docs](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Range.html#isConnected(com.google.common.collect.Range)).  This is mentioned explicitly in the `RangeSet` doc: "Note that the behavior of Range.isEmpty() and Range.isConnected(Range) may not be as expected on discrete ranges."

Comment: I agree, you added your comment while I was editing my answer with the quote of isConnected doc ;) However, I still think the doc is wrong concerning the `[10, 15) (15, 20)` thing.